# Get an _id from mongoose model by name. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Problem is - i can't define variable inside this function (console.log is working), and can't find another way how to get _id from this damn model.

```
 User.findOne({name: name}, function(err, user) {
    var test = user._id;
    console.log(user._id);
});
```

Comment: Where you want to use your `_id`, elaborate more on how you want to use. In general scenarios, you can use `Promises`.

Comment: I need it for use in module 'mongoose-friends', one of the methods require _id. I mean plain string _id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use async module https://github.com/caolan/async to get users first and then use their user._id to make requestFriend call.

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        User.findOne({name: userOneName}, callback);
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        User.findOne({name: userTwoName}, callback);
    }
}, function(err, users) {
    User.requestFriend(users.two._id, users.one._id, callback);
});
```